# How to specify order of returned query when using Table Value Constructor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT VAL 
     FROM TABLE 
     WHERE IDENTIFIER = E.id) 
FROM 
    (VALUES ('V1'), ('V2'), ('V3')) E(id)
```

I am using the table-valued constructor syntax `(SELECT FROM VALUES)` for performance reasons as I need to run hundreds of queries in bulk for data validation.

However, the results of this query is not guaranteed to be in the same order as the values I pass in.

It is the same order most of the time but not always. How can I guarantee the results of this query are in the same order as the values I pass in?

Comment: specify an `order by` clause.

Comment: I found an alternate solution, doing `SELECT id, (SELECT....` will return the value passed in, I can use this to rebuild the order.  I'll leave the question open as it is still a valid question

Comment: @vkp there is nothing to order by, if I add the id then this is possible and works

Comment: You are getting those rows returned in the same order by dumb luck. If you don't specify an order then you have no way of ensuring the order returned. Read this article on the topic. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `order` dummy column to the values, and `ORDER BY` that:

```
Select  Val
From    Table   T
Join    (Values ('V1', 1), 
                ('V2', 2), 
                ('V3', 3)) E (id, ord) 
        On E.Id = T.IDENTIFIER
Order By E.ord;
```

Comment: great, it was easier for me to do the following:
`SELECT (SELECT VAL FROM ...), id, FROM (VALUES...) E(id) ORDER BY id` as it was existing code, but this is still probably nicer if I had to do it again